# How can I extract monthly average value from the Leaf Area Index (LAI) of set of points?

Tags: google-earth-engine, vegetation-index, lai

I'm trying to get the monthly average value of the Leaf Area Index (LAI) between 2016 to 2019 from a set of sample points (n = 25) imported via Assets. However, when exporting the LAI values extracted, 25 tables are generated, one for each sample point and not a single table with the monthly average value of all points. Below is the code that I have being used:

I'm new to Google Earth Engine and the Java programming language, so I apologize if the answer to this question is obvious. I've spent a lot of time trying to find a solution to this problem and I feel like I'm not succeeding.

````
var startyear = 2016;
var endyear = 2019;

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

var startdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startyear, 1, 1);
var enddate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endyear, 12, 31);

var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear, endyear);

var mataseca = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-fhsf01/assets/25");


Map.addLayer(mataseca, {}, "Mataseca", false);

Map.centerObject(mataseca, 12);

var collection = ee
  .ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
  .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
  .filterBounds(mataseca)
  .filterMetadata("CLOUD_COVER", "less_than", 10);


var addIAF = function (image) {
  var iaf = image
    .expression(
      "0.54 + 9.96 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED))",
      {
        NIR: image.select("B5"),
        RED: image.select("B4"),
      }
    )
    .rename("IAF");
  return image.addBands(iaf);
};


collection = collection.map(addIAF);

var iaf_mean = collection.select("IAF").mean();

print(ui.Chart.image.series(collection.select("IAF"), mataseca));

Map.addLayer(
  iaf_mean,
  {
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    palette: [
      "SandyBrown",
      "DarkKhaki",
      "Gold",
      "Yellow",
      "GreenYellow",
      "Lime",
      "LimeGreen",
      "Green",
    ],
  },
  "IAF",
  false
);

print(collection);

var testeiaf = iaf_mean.select("IAF").reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: mataseca,
  scale: 30,
});

print("Mean iaf", testeiaf);

//IAF - Month

var iafmensal = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(

  years
    .map(function (ano) {
      

      return months.map(function (mes) {
       

        var iaf_month = collection
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ano, ano, "year"))
          .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(mes, mes, "month"))
          .mean() 
          .clip(mataseca);

        return iaf_month
          .set("year", ano) 
          .set("month", mes) 
          .set("date", ee.Date.fromYMD(ano, mes, 1)) 
          .set("system:time_start", ee.Date.fromYMD(ano, mes, 1).millis());
      });
    })
    .flatten()
);

print(iafmensal);

var chartP = ui.Chart.image
  .seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: iafmensal,
    regions: mataseca,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 2500,
    xProperty: "system:time_start",
    seriesProperty: "Nome",
  })
  .setOptions({
    title: "IAF médio mensal (2016 a 2019) da uc Mata Seca",
    hAxis: { title: "Intervalo de tempo" },
    vAxis: { title: "iaf" },
  })
  .setChartType("ColumnChart");

print(chartP);



////////////////////////
var num_points = mataseca.size();
var points_List = mataseca.toList(num_points);
var n = points_List.size().getInfo();

var point_list = mataseca.geometry().geometries();

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var point = point_list.get(i);

  var point2 = ee.Geometry(point).buffer(100);

   var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

 
  var scale = iafmensal.first().projection().nominalScale().multiply(0.05);
  print(scale);
  iafmensal = iafmensal.filter(
    ee.Filter.listContains(
      "system:band_names",
      iafmensal.first().bandNames().get(0)
    )
  );

  var fill = function (img, ini) {
    var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);
    var ft2 = img.reduceRegions(point2, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30);
    var date = img.date().format("YYYYMM");
    var ft3 = ft2.map(function (f) {
      return f.set("date", date);
    });
    return inift.merge(ft3);
  };


  var profile = ee.FeatureCollection(iafmensal.iterate(fill, ft));
  print(profile, "profile");


  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: profile,
    description: "VegetationIndexes_Point_" + i,
    folder: "Earth Engine",
    fileNamePrefix: "VegetationIndexes_Point_" + i,
    fileFormat: "CSV",
    selectors: ["date", "iaf", "IAF"],
  });
}```

<https://code.earthengine.google.com/0653bfa3cc3d1d985a82456c276fc558>
````